# migrating from ngRoute to ui.router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

I have a problem with migrating from ngroute to ui.router:

using ngroute i have couple angular files:

module.js

```
angular.module('betTogether', ['ngRoute']);
```

route.js

```
angular.module('betTogether').config(['$routeProvider',
    function (
        $routeProvider
    ) {
          $routeProvider.
              when('/descriptionBets', {
                  templateUrl: 'descriptionBets',
                  controller: 'descriptionBetsCtrl'
              }).
              when('/normalBets', {
                  templateUrl: 'normal',
                  controller: 'normalBetsCtrl'
              }).
              when('/addBet', {
                  templateUrl: 'addBet',
                  controller: 'addBetCtrl'
              }).
              otherwise({
                  redirectTo: '/descriptionBets'
              });
}]);
```

normalBets.js

```
angular.module('betTogether').controller('normalBetsCtrl', [
'$scope','$http',

function($scope,$http){

    $scope.typeBetsImages = [{link: "images/basketball.png", title:"basketball"},
                {link: "images/tenis.png", title: "tenis"},
                {link: "images/volleyball.png", title: "volleyball"},
                {link: "images/football.png", title:"football"}
    ];

    $http.get("/normalBets").success(function(data){
        $scope.normalBets = data;
    });

}]);
```

...and rest of controllers. And everything works ok.
Now i want to migrate to ui-router. so i change module.js and route.js like that:

module.js

```
angular.module('betTogether', ['ui.router']);
```

route.js

```
angular.module('betTogether').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
                // For any unmatched url, send to /business
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/descriptionBets")

                $stateProvider
                        .state('descriptionBets', {//State demonstrating Nested views
                            url: "/descriptionBets",
                            templateUrl: "descriptionBets",
                            controller: "descriptionBetsCtrl"
                        })
                        .state('normalBets', {//nested state [products is the nested state of business state]
                            url: "/normalBets",
                            templateUrl: "normal",
                            controller: "normalBetsCtrl"
                        })
                        .state('addBet', {//nested state [services is the nested state of business state]
                            url: "/addBet",
                            templateUrl: "addBet",
                            controller: "addBetCtrl"
                        });

            }]);
```

and it doesnt work. i have error:

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/$injector/nomod?p0=betTogether angular.min.js:6:417
```

... and it is for 1st line of each controllers.

Someone could help me?

PS: sorry for my english, hope You understand all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the order of your `<script>` imports in your `index.html`. The likelihood is that you've included the `ui-router` module after your `betTogether` module whereas it should come before it because `betTogether` depends on `ui.router`.

Comment: i put angular and ui-router scripts on the beginning of my imports - it works. So, thanks a lot :)